# AS3 - How to get next array Index and how i change my Function

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, server

i have connectAgain function when connection is lose i addchild button,  when i click this button call connectAgain function in this function have serverUrl and serverPort only one ip and port this is current system and its work.

But now, i have 4 or 5 ip and port. i guess i add array or dictionary or Object, and when connection is lose i click button and call ip and port inside the array but every connection lose i want to call next ip and port not same ip and port.

please help me thanks this is my current function. How can i do it ?

```
public static function connectAgain(serverUrl:String = "", serverPort:int = 0):void {


        serverUrl = myGameClass.serverUrl;
        serverPort = myGameClass.serverPort;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some helper classes as follows:

```
class UriIterator {
    private var _availableAddresses: Vector.<UriVO> = new Vector.<UriVO>();

    public function withAddress(host: String, port: int): UriIterator {
        const a: UriVO = new UriVO(host, port);
        _availableAddresses.push(a);
        return this;
    }

    public function get next(): UriVO
    {
        return _availableAddresses.length ? _availableAddresses.pop() : null;
    }
}

class UriVO  {
    private var _host: String;
    private var _port: int;
    public function Address(host: String, port: int) {
        _host = host;
        _port = port;
    }

    public function get host():String {
        return _host;
    }

    public function get port():int {
        return _port;
    }
}
```

Somewhere on init you create the iterator:

```
...
const urisToTry: UriIterator = new UriIterator()
        .withAddress("http://urlone.com", 1211)
        .withAddress("http://urltwo.com", 1212)
        .withAddress("http://urlthree.com", 1213)
        .withAddress("http://urlfour.com", 1214)
...
```

Then, in reconnect function you can call the `next()` function to retrieve next url for connection:

```
const nextUri: UriVO = urisToTry.next;
if (nextUri)
    connectAgain(nextUri.host, nextUri.port);
else
    // you've tried all uris and connection failed.
```

Comment: Hi Nbooo, i add your system and great works but i have one more question for this system please help thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750178/as3-how-to-i-turn-head-of-the-vector-list

Comment: Hi Nboo my last question right there please help thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755573/as3-how-i-add-auto-next-on-list-when-i-click-connect-again-button