# AS3 How to i turn head of the Vector list?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, vector, server

I have a Vector for ip and port list and socket connection, When connection lose i click button and call the next ip and port from vector list.

My question is when finish my list how to  i turn head of the list ?

This my current code

```
public class UriIterator 
{
     private var _availableAddresses: Vector.<SocketConnection> = new Vector.<SocketConnection>();


    public function UriIterator() 
    {

    }


    public function withAddress(host: String, port: int): UriIterator {
        const a: SocketConnection = new SocketConnection(host, port);
        _availableAddresses.push(a);
        return this;
    }

     public function get next(): SocketConnection{
        return _availableAddresses.length ? _availableAddresses.pop() : null;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current implementation you can traverse the list only once. You need to change the code to keep the list unmodified:

```
public class UriIterator 
{
    private var _currentIndex:int = 0;
    private var _availableAddresses: Vector.<SocketConnection> = new Vector.<SocketConnection>();


    public function withAddress(host: String, port: int): UriIterator {
        const a: SocketConnection = new SocketConnection(host, port);
        _availableAddresses.push(a);
        return this;
    }

    public function get first():SocketConnection {
        _currentIndex = 0;
        if (_currentIndex >= _availableAddresses.length) 
            return null;
        return _availableAddresses[_currentIndex++];
   }

   public function get next(): SocketConnection {
        if (_currentIndex >= _availableAddresses.length) 
            return null;
        return _availableAddresses[_currentIndex++];
   }
}
```

Now to get the first entry you call `const firstConn:SocketConnection = iterator.first` and to get the rest of them, just keep calling `iterator.next`.

Comment: Thanks for Answer! @Nbooo

How i add auto next on list when i click reconnect Button ?

Answer (score 1):

A small tweak to your code needed:

```
public function get next():SocketConnection
{
    // Get the next one.
    var result:SocketConnection = _availableAddresses.pop();

    // Put it back at the other end of the list.
    _availableAddresses.unshift(result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer i solve like this/



`private var currentIndex:int = 0;


public function get next():SocketConnection {
   var address = _availableAddresses[currentIndex];
   currentIndex++;
   if (currentIndex > _availableAddresses.length - 1)
    currentIndex = 0;
   return address;
  }`

Comment: my other question help please...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755573/as3-how-i-add-auto-next-on-list-when-i-click-connect-again-button

thanks

Comment: @KaraEski That one is not a question, it is request for working code without showing what you've tried so far.